# Login with capacitor-firebase-auth and link the newly added Google Account with the previous anonymous account

Tags: android, google-oauth, ionic4, google-signin, capacitor

**Initial Situation:**

I need to implement a Google sign-up where a user can link his anonymous account to his Google Account.

**Therefore I use:**

Ionic 5.2.2
Capacitor 1.1.1
capacitor-firebase-auth plugin 0.1.5

**With that setup I achieved already:**

Login works fine. A **new** User with a linked Google Account was created.

**Problem:**

After the sign up there are **two users**, the anonymous one and that one with the Google Account, instead of only one merged (linked) User.

**What I've tried already**

Since I'm on an Android device (Galaxy S10 +), I can't just use the *currentUser.linkWithRedirect()* or *currentUser.linkWithPopup()* methods. That's why I'm using the capacitor community plug-in *capacitor-firebase-auth*, which is at an early stage but already works for regular login.

After the user has chosen his Google Account the method *cfaSignIn()* is done and the subscription is activated. As a result of the callback I have an user object:

```
linkAccountWithGoogleAuthProviderFromApp(): Promise<string> {

    return new Promise<string>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      this.subscriptionHandler.addSubscription(

        cfaSignIn('google.com').subscribe(async (user) => {

          // At this point I have the new Google-User and
          // I need to link him to the anonymous account

          resolve(user.email);
        },
          err => {
            reject(err)
          }
        )

      )
    })
  }
```

**Question**

Does anyone have any idea how to link the newly created user with the previous anonymous user without making the detour to migrate the anonymous user's data to the new Google user and then delete the anonymous user?

Comment: hi bro please share full code of capacitor firebase auth how to import subscriptionHandler

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm stuck with this. The more approximate solution I found was [this comment](https://github.com/baumblatt/capacitor-firebase-auth/issues/127#issuecomment-724610523) on capacitor-firebase-auth issues, but it didn't work it complaint with "Error: This credential is already associated with a different user account"